# Vue3 equivalent to create component instance via new Vue()

Tags: vue.js

I have a data-modelling library that uses underlying Vue2 component instances, eg:

```
const Person = Vue.extend({
    name: 'Person',
    //- ... data, computed, watch, methods, events, etc...
})

const person = new Person({ ... })
```

I can't find docs to determine if there is an equivalent method of creating a new component instance detached from the DOM and OUTSIDE of the main App's context.

Certainly `createApp()` isn't what I'm looking for - from the [Vue3 API Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp)

I guess `defineComponent()` seems to be the way to define the component (d'uh!) ... but since there is no constructor, there seems to be no way to instantiate it outside of the Apps context (ie mounting it)

Is there such a thing? Have I perhaps been *versioned-out* of my sweet sweet data modelling library?!? Tell me it's not so!